# Python Notebook Panda DataFrame doesn't line break

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Python Jupyter Notebook displaying some pandas DataFrame.

I have some data frame and I would like to display the data with a fixed column width. To do so, I would like to be able to line break a cell.

For example, I have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : ['one', 'two', 'This is very long string very long string very long string very long string\nvery long string very long string']})
df
```

I would like to set the size of my column and have line break.
I tried the following:
`pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 2000)`

But it only set the maximum size. Is there a way to set column width for each column?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try overwrite CSS defaults from pandas, though it might depend on version
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/961

Line breaking in CSS is word-wrap

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'word-wrap': 'break-word'})
```